# EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

I wrote this function to find the index of the last max number in the list.
But it returns following error "EOFError: EOF when reading a line".
Should I add a checker if empty input comes?

```
def last_indexof_max(numbers):
    index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] >= numbers[index]:
            index = i
    return index

numbers = [int(number) for number in input().split()]
print(last_indexof_max(numbers))
```

Comment: What do you give as input?

Comment: @Asocia, I run this code through online course IDE. It has a built-in checker which returns this error. I don't have access to their input

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the code shown. Can you provide enough information to reproduce your issue? What online course IDE are you using?

Comment: @yanamazault Oh, I see. Maybe the issue is you are reading a single line but they are giving the input line by line? We really can't help unless we see the input format.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it's JetBrains Python Developer course.https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/7321

Comment: @Asocia, yeah, got it. I think I will ask the course support team, maybe they can provide inputs they use for testing code provided by students

Comment: From the link you shared: "You do NOT need to work with the input, call the function, or print anything!" So that is the problem with your code.

Comment: @Asocia oh...exactly, I should be more attentive. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably taking the wrong input. In your case, the fault is that your function doesn't have an input to read and it gives the EOF error which means that the `input()` didn't receive any input and hence your program gets `EOF error`.

For the link you shared, only writing the function is enough since taking the input and outputting the result is handled by server. The following should work fine without any errors.

```
def last_indexof_max(numbers):
    index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] >= numbers[index]:
            index = i
    return index
```

Comment: @yanamazault Glad to help ! If you feel an answer solved the problem, feel free to mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.